# issue with data not coming through to java servlet

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jquery, servlets

I am trying to simply post some canned json to a servlet using jquery ajax. I am using the google app engine. I catch the call in the debugger and inspect the request, but its parameters map is always null...

any help is greatly appreciated!

here is the  ajax call

```
           $.ajax({ url: "/UDF/register",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  xx={"a" : "s"},
                    dataType : 'json'  });
```

and i catch the doPost in the servlet that the url is mapped , i look at the request parameters (maybe im looking in the wrong place?) and they are null.

thanks in advance!

Comment: title should have included from ajax :( sorry

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i was looking in the wrong parameters map on the request object. Im sorry if i led anyone here for no reason.